# Entity Framework: How to add a new table at runtime

Tags: entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework and want to use it in my application but need to know if it can do what I need it to do.

So I will have a database that has a table of market data. In the app I want to import data for a new stock and have that data added to the database. So each stock will have it own table in the database. So the question is how do I add a new table to my Entity framework DB at run time?

Comment: No, you don't want that. Read up on normalization and simply add a `StockID` column.

Comment: are you sure u want to create a table for each `stock`? I suggest to rethink your strategy

Comment: Guys, thanks very much for the heads up.